# Hibernate how to build sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following query in Postgres 11

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (account.name) *
FROM sys_accounts AS account 
  INNER JOIN sys_activities AS activity ON account.guid=activity.account_guid 
WHERE activity.datefinish IS NOT NULL 
  AND (extract(day from NOW() - activity.datefinish)) > 60 
  AND dc_status_guid='df11a68c-20d3-46e2-840f-2e4548aacf1b'  
ORDER  BY  account.name,activity.datefinish DESC
```

How can I run that through Hibernate (5.4)

I need get all accounts where last task closed > 60 days ago

Java structure like

```
Account (oneToMany){
                    Activity1 :finishdate |stage ....
                    Activity2 :finishdate |stage ....
                    ......
                   }
```

I don't understand how to write this request with hibernate syntax HQL or CRITERIA. With HQL i get error:Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 17 [SELECT DISTINCT ON (account.name)* FROM sys_accounts AS account INNER JOIN sys_activities AS activity ON account.guid=activity.account_guid WHERE activity.datefinish IS NOT NULL AND dc_status_guid='df11a68c-20d3-46e2-840f-2e4548aacf1b' ORDER BY account.name,activity.datefinish DESC]

Comment: Unrelated, but:  `(extract(day from NOW() - activity.datefinish)) > 60 ` is not going to do what you think it does. You should use `and now()  - activity.datefinish > interval '60 day'`

Comment: Thanks, I do not understand how to write this request with hibernate syntax HQL or CRITERIA. With  HQL i get error:Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 17 [SELECT DISTINCT ON (account.name)* FROM sys_accounts AS account INNER JOIN sys_activities AS activity ON account.guid=activity.account_guid WHERE activity.datefinish IS NOT NULL AND dc_status_guid='df11a68c-20d3-46e2-840f-2e4548aacf1b' ORDER  BY  account.name,activity.datefinish DESC]